# Is it safe to install Firefox 3.6 alongside an existing Firefox 6+ installation?

Tags: windows-7, firefox-3.6, firefox

About 9% of my website's users are still on Firefox 3.6. While encouraging them to upgrade, I still need to test that the website looks presentable in 3.6, but I have Firefox 6 installed on my computer (Windows 7 x64).

Is it safe to install Firefox 3.6 without it interfering with my existing Firefox 6 installation?

Comment: as he said it is hectic use ff portable .. i tried a dual install  and ended up being sorry ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is the possibility/likelihood(?) of problems.

My suggestion is that you download the [portable versions of Firefox](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable). You can find older versions at the bottom of that page.

Answer (score 2):

No need for portable. Just copy your profile and use profile manager to use FF 3.6 and 6 or whatever version you need.

Fire up with "-no-remote" to run second version of Firefox side by side.

Examples:

Run along other version and open Profile Manager at startup:

```
somepath\firefox.exe -ProfileManager -no-remote
```

Run along other version and open with a profile named "FF3":

```
somepath\firefox.exe -P "FF3" -no-remote
```

Run along other version and open with a profile named "default":

```
somepath\firefox.exe -P "default" -no-remote
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also look at application virtualization with something like [Thinapp](http://www.vmware.com/products/thinapp/overview.html), [App-V](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/enterprise/solutions/virtualization/products/app-v.aspx), [Cameyo](http://www.cameyo.com/) or any number of others.